# Issue with building table schema

Tags: database-design

I have a html table that needs to be filled by an accountant (Student project), the table is editable and should be stored in DB.

Table:
[Html Table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiAfp.jpg)

As I mentioned in the caption, the asset pool columns could be me more or less.
I don't now if I am lacking Exp. or its just too hard. but I don't have the slightest idea of how the table schema should be.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to create an asset pool table. It is probably because we have no clue wnat your application is about and what various columns and rows in that table represent. SO is not really suitable for discussing database design for a specific application as it requires a good understanding of the subject matter and also your specific requirements.

Comment: your right, I am sorry I didn't explain a lot (newbie). in case I created asset pool table, how would I know which asset is it for ( Revnues - EBIT .. etc). do I need to create type column with every asset?

Comment: Again, we don't know the answer to that question. We do not know how you store your assets and what those assets represent.